# How can I make sure my RNG numbers are unique?

Tags: nearprotocol, near-sdk-as

I'm trying to select 2 random items out of a list using the RNG class. The problem is occasionally I get the same 2 numbers and I'd like them to be unique. I tried using a while loop to get another number if the it's the same as the last one but adding even a simple while loop results in an "Exceeded prepaid gas" error. What am I not understanding?

```
//simplified for posting question
var lengthOfList = 10
var numItemsWanted = 2
//Get more rng numbers than I need incase of duplicates
const rng = new RNG<u32>(lenghtOfList, lengthOfList)

for(let i = 0; i < numItemsWanted; i++) {
    var r = rng.next()
    while (r == rng.last()) {
        r = rng.next()
    }
    newList.push(oldList[r])
}
```

Working:

```
//simplified for posting question
var lengthOfList = 10
var numItemsWanted = 2
//Get more rng numbers than I need incase of duplicates
const rng = new RNG<u32>(lenghtOfList, lengthOfList)
let r = rng.next()
let last = r + 1
for(let i = 0; i < numItemsWanted; i++) {
    newList.push(oldList[r])
    last = r
    r = rng.next()
    while (r == last) {
        r = rng.next()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is about `near-sdk-as`, the smart contract development kit for AssemblyScript on the NEAR platform

you can see how RNG is used in this example
https://github.com/Learn-NEAR/NCD.L1.sample--lottery/blob/ff6cddaa8cac4d8fe29dd1a19b38a6e3c7045363/src/lottery/assembly/lottery.ts#L12-L13

```js
class Lottery {
  private chance: f64 = 0.20

  play(): bool {
    const rng = new RNG<u32>(1, u32.MAX_VALUE);
    const roll = rng.next();
    logging.log("roll: " + roll.toString());
    return roll <= <u32>(<f64>u32.MAX_VALUE * this.chance);
  }
}
```

and how the constructor is implemented here:
https://github.com/near/near-sdk-as/blob/f3707a1672d6da6f6d6a75cd645f8cbdacdaf495/sdk-core/assembly/math.ts#L152

the first argument is the length of the buffer holding random numbers generated from the seed.  you can use the `next()` method to get more numbers from this buffer with each call

```js
export class RNG<T> {
  constructor(len: u32, public max: u32 = 10_000) {
    let real_len = len * sizeof<T>();
    this.buffer = math.randomBuffer(real_len);
    this._last = this.get(0);
  }

  next(): T {}
}
```

Comment: I thought I understood but I don't fully.
`new RNG<u32>(5,10)`
creates a list of 5 random numbers that have a max value of 10? or do I misunderstand that part?

Calling rng.next() gives the next number?

What does this._last represent? both RNG.next() and RNG.last() return this._last.

Comment: i think that's correct, yes. and it's possible there's a bug of course

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the item from `oldList` once picked, it would be imposible to picked it again.

Another aproach is to shuffle your `oldList` and then pick the first two items.

Comment: I'd like to keep the original list intact, but shuffling it is a perfectly elegant solution I think. Thanks